# Combining binary and continous response variables in a predictive model

Tags: regression, predictive-models

I just wanted to get some clarification on whether I'm thinking about this problem the right way or not.

I have some sports-betting related data where each observation is a game. I have multiple predictors (weather, time of day, teams, etc.). For the response variables I'm using the pre-game betting spread and actual score of the game to measure how "good" the pre-game spread was. Here are my response variables:

1. Binary - Whether the team selected to win, according to the betting spread, was correct or not
2. Continuous - How close the predicted spread was to the actual outcome of the game. For this I'm just simply using : *Difference = |Predicted Spread - Actual Score Spread|*

Since my goal is to build a predictive model, the first way I thought about approaching it would be to simply create two separate models. To answer the first question you can just use any classification procedure and to predict if the predicted team won; and for the second model, you can run a regression to see how close the actual score is likely to be to the pre-game spread.

But now I'm thinking these two response variables should be combined because it would seem to lose a lot of predictive information running them seperately. Would it be more appropriate to code a single response variable as being: *Predicted Spread - Actual Score Spread*? This would allow the response variable to take on negative values for games that were predicted incorrectly and you'd still get a spread prediction.

Perhaps I'm just overthinking this, but I think it's throwing me off because it's a prediction of a prediction. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nothing wrong with it. I guess you have seen this research?  https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1527002510395864

Comment: No I haven't seen that research, Thanks for the link!